# Phasors of power supply Vs1 in one example

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, phase, phasor

I read one example in my note:

If \$V1=1=+j2\$ and \$V2=12+j12\$, phasor of power supply Vs1 is: \$29+j59\$, but I couldn't get it. I think it's wrong and the solution is \$29+j57\$. Could anyone help me?

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

Well, at node 1 we have:

$$\frac{V_{S1} - V_1}{2 + j2} = \frac{V_1}{\frac{1}{2}||(-j2)} + \frac{V_1 - V_2}{j4}$$

which can be solved for \$V_{S1}\$.  Is this the equation you have?

If so, are you sure you've solved correctly for \$V_{S1}\$?

Also, is \$V_1 = 1 + j2\$?

Comment: Dear Alfred, yes i have the above equation. would you please complete the for Vs1? i means the last answer is 29+j57 or 29+j59?

Comment: Dear @Alfred, would you pleaes complete your answer?